# How do I get a previous version of my code using VS2012 with Git and Team Foundation Service?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I am unable to see anything in the VS2012 user interface or help documentation/blogs to do this.

I have signed up for a free account at http://tfs.visualstudio.com/. I have installed VS2012 Update 2 CTP, and installed the necessary Git extension. Everything else so far is working really well.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the easiest way to switch between the different commits of your Git repo is to use the command line. By doing so you'll have a better control of your repo and you'll be able to use every features offered by Git (just a few of them are accessible from Visual Studio user interface).

I suggest you to install [posh-git](http://dahlbyk.github.io/posh-git/) that is a great PowerShell tool for Git. Here is a very useful video available on Microsoft Virtual Academy to guide you in the Git installation/configuration process: [Install and Configure Git](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/using-git-with-visual-studio-2013-jump-start) (jump directly to the Session 2).

As soon as you've posh-git installed and configured, you'll get full power of Git! And the action you are looking for is very easy to complete:

1. `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` to show your history and identify the previous version of your code that you want to switch to
2. `git checkout <commit>` to switch from your current version to the desired one

Hope this will help you, don't hesitate to have a look at every sessions of the tutorial in order to better understand every aspect of Git.